# Matlab audio splicing

Tags: matlab, audio

```
[song, fs, bits]=wavread('song.wav');
[snare, fs, bits]=wavread('snare.wav');
```

I have read in two wavs, a song wav and a snare wav, and I want to get the snare wav to play during the sound wav inbetween each beat. I can get the snare to play at the very beginning of the song by doing this:

```
slice=song(1:snare_length);
song(1:snare_length)=slice+snare;
```

However, I don't know how to get the snare to play during each beat in the song. Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to manually determine beat length in samples. Then repeat the snare with that period, with an initial offset if needed, and add the repeated snare to the song.

You can do it along these lines.

```
n = 30000; %// beat time in samples
k = 10000; %// initial offset for snare
C = 1; %// 1 or 2 for mono or stereo respectively

L = length(song);
M = length(snare);
snares = zeros(L,C); %// this will contain the repeated snares
pos = k;
while pos < L-M
    snares(pos+(0:M-1),:) = snare;
    pos = pos + n;
end
song_with_snares = .7*song + .3*snares; %// adjust gain factors as needed
```